# Hide bootstrap progress bar after 100%

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to hide a progress bar after it finishes the animation (at 100%). How can I do it? Here is the code working but I just don't know how to hide it afterwards:

```js
$(".progress-bar").animate({
  width: "100%"
}, 5000);
```

```css
.progress.active .progress-bar {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 progress-container">
  <div class="progress progress-striped active">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:0%">Loading...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And there's also a Fiddle to show it (my code is based on that, what this fiddle does is to load from 0 to 70% in 2.5 seconds but it is exactly the same as I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/WEYKL/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) function from [jQuery's `animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

```
$(".progress-bar").animate({
    width: "100%"
}, 5000, function() {
    $(this).closest('.progress').fadeOut();
});
```